# how to get images from another domain

Tags: php

```
function givemeG($path) {
$files = glob($path . '*.jpg');
$cs=" class=\"act\"";
foreach($files as $img) { 
    echo "<img" . $cs . " src=" . "\"" . $img . "\"" . " alt=\"img\">";
    $cs="";
    echo "\n";
}
}

$path = "frederic/";
givemeG($path);
```

This writes img tags for all images inside `frederic` folder

How can I do the same but instead of `frederic` folder I need the images from another domain (the same host server).

Simply replacing `path` doesn't work:

```
$path = "http://www.codee.site50.net/frederic/";
givemeG($path);
```

Comment: Obviously file browsing isn't even enabled for this folder. You cannot achieve that if you don't meet this minimal requirement. And even if it was, you cannot browse it with `glob()`. This URL will fetch you an HTML document either it is representing the content of a folder or not, and you have to extract the file names by parsing the document body.

Comment: @Havenard, thanks a lot for your explanation. Seems you should place it as answer.